# Assign random color to matplotlib graph

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, rgb

I am trying to plot some polygons in matplotlib, and I've been able to use pre-defined HTML colors, but I would like to use random RGB tuples. However, I can't figure it out.

Here's the code I've been trying:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.use('agg')
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import random
>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>>> ax.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,6], (.4, .5, .6))
```

And I get this error: `raise ValueError('third arg must be a format string')`

What I would like to do eventually, is to do this:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> import random
>>> matplotlib.use('agg')
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import random
>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>>> ax.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,6], (random.random(), random.random(), random.random()))
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
ax.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,6], color=(.4, .5, .6))
```

Reading from [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot),

> You do not need to use format strings, which are just abbreviations. All of the line properties can be controlled by keyword arguments. For example, you can set the color, marker, linestyle, and markercolor with:
>
> ```
> plot(x, y, color='green', linestyle='dashed', marker='o',
>      markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=12).
> ```

Answer (score 11):

To get random color:

```
import numpy as np
ax.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,6], color=np.random.rand(3,1))
```

Comment: I think he meant an arbitrary color to be named, not one chosen at random.

Comment: without numpy, you can use `color=(random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1))`

Comment: color=random.rand(3,1) does not work very well, explicitly use ```np.random.rand(3)```
because: 
1. random will conflict with numpy's random
2. this will generate a 1d array which can be accepted by the color attribute in matplotlib as it asks for a tuple, whereas random.rand(3,1) gives a nd-array which will throw an error